# Rails - How to render js in an html response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

I have an action 'index', that when called via ajax, renders index.js which renders a partial:

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'index') %>");
```

How do I make the same thing happen in the html response?
I tried:

```
format.html { render "index.js" }
```

And although I don't get any errors, the js code doesn't seem to run, because the partial doesn't render.

Comment: Why would you want an html response to return a javascript file? I don't think the browser would evaluate this properly, since the request is expecting html.

Comment: @Samo: Sometimes (eg jQuery), any javascript found in script tags inside html is executed.

Comment: @Swanand: yes, but 99miles is returning a javascript file which I assume contains only javascript. If there are script tags in the javascript file, then those are html tags, so the file shouldn't be a .js file.

Comment: @Samo: Yes, you are right. Which brings my question to the asker, 99miles: Do you want to render the `index.js` file as you have shown, or you want to render the `index` partial like in `format.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the script inside `<script>` tag?

Your `index.html.erb` would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'index') %>");
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The default render is a shortcut for `render :action => :action_name`. To specify a filesystem path use `render :file => "index.js"`